# Publish to twitter using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

Is there any way to publish to twitter using javascript??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Tweet Box` in [Twitter Anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin) to tweet via Javascript. The user has to  sign in before tweeting.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the Same Origin Policy you need to post to your server and dispatch a request to twitter from there. Using this approach you can connect to twitter via JS.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this way?

http://www.saschakimmel.com/2009/05/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tweet-this-button-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Php and jquery with the help of this tutorial I think you can make it possible

[Tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/09/twitter-oauth-home-timeline-display.html)

[Demo](http://labs.9lessons.info/)