# Sending tweet on twitter using as3 without navigating to url

Tags: android, iphone, actionscript-3, twitter

I need to tweet on twitter some specific message. I need to do that for iphone and andorid using as3. While searching, I got a solution to navigateToUrl (to url 'http://twitter.com/home?status=message') and post, its working but it remains to the account of the user. I searched some apis also but didnt find any useful way to sending a tweet from a as3 flash app. Can any one please help me??

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using URLRequests to hit the twitter API after logging in with oAuth. There are also a couple of libs available to you for doing this.

http://wiki.swfjunkie.com/tweetr

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExternalInterface with javascript to send tweets.

[See here.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)
[And here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723257/publish-to-twitter-using-javascript)